# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'autodiscover_tasks' if run Django with Gunicorn

Tags: django, celery, gunicorn, celerybeat

I have a `docker-compose` file like this:

```
backend:
    image: ${API_IMAGE}
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./data/server/static/:/usr/src/api/static
      - ./data/server/uploads/:/usr/src/api/uploads
    restart: always
frontend:
    image: ${FRONTEND_IMAGE}
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - ./data/server/logs:/usr/src/web/logs
    - ./configs/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./data/server/static/:/usr/src/app/static
    - ./data/server/uploads/:/usr/src/app/uploads
    restart: always
celery:
    image: ${API_IMAGE}
    env_file:
      - .env
    working_dir: /usr/src/api/
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'core.settings'
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: /bin/sh -c "celery -E -A core worker -l info"

  beat:
    image: ${API_IMAGE}
    env_file:
      - .env
    working_dir: /usr/src/api/
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'core.settings'
    depends_on:
      - celery
    command: /bin/sh -c "celery -A core beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"
```

Everything is accessed through the `frontend` container which is a Nginx application using proxy to send request to others containers.

The backend is running with the CMD in a `bash` file with:

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - -w 4 core.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:80 &
```

Everything is fine, and running. But if I access the admin site, and try to use Celery Beat to create a Periodic Task, show me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
backend_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
backend_1  |     return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
backend_1  | KeyError: '_modules'
backend_1  | 
backend_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 684, in <listcomp>
backend_1  |     for pkg in fixup.autodiscover_tasks()
backend_1  | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'autodiscover_tasks'
```

But, if I run the `backend` with:

```
python manage.py runserver 80
```

No problem, no exception. Everything is fine!

When I run with gunicorn, show the error when try access Periodic Tasks from Celery Beat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that when I run `python manage.py runserver` there is a line in manage.py that set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, but if I run with gunicorn this environment var isn't populated for celery works fine.

I set the environment in `backend` container and everythings works!

```
.
.
.
backend:
  environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'core.settings'
.
.
.
```